# Отправка фрейма закрытия WebSocket Linux C

Tags: javascript, linux, c, websocket

Пишу простой Socket server под Linux на С. Столкнулся к непонятной для меня проблемой.

```
//открываю socket
//жду подключения
//обрабатываю заголовок
//соединение установлено, тестовые данные отправляются отлично
//хочу закрыть соединение

//формирую биты закрытия. На моей машине char 1 байт.
char close_soket[4] = {0x88,0x02,0x00,0x00};
//отправляю
int send_data = send(data_socket, close_soket,4,0);
//обрабатываю ошибки
//закрываю soket
```

При отправке закрывающего фрейма у клиента (браузер, код на js) должно сработать событие onClose(стандартная функция WebSocket) о чистом закрытии, но закрытие происходит экстренное с кодом 1006.
Пробовал формировать и следующий фрейм закрытия с кодом закрытия и сообщением:

```
char close_soket[6] = {0x88,0x04,0x03,0xe8,'C','l'};
```

В этом варианте такая же ошибка.

Код клиента:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://ip:port");
  socket.onopen  = function() {
    console.log("Connection success"); //срабатывает во всех случаях
  };
  socket.onclose = function(event) {
    if (event.wasClean) {
      console.log("Close connection");
    } else {
      console.log("Hard close connection"); //срабатывает с ошибкой 1006 
    }
    console.log("Code: " + event.code + "\nreason: " + event.reason);
  }
  socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log("Recv data: " + event.data);
  }
  socket.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.message);
  }
```

Где может быть ошибка? Что не верно? Несколько дне ломаю голову. Спецификацию RFC 6455 читал, но может что то упустил. Флеши, в фреймах, вроде не нужны.

Comment: покажите, какую именно ошибку выдает `console.log("Error: " + error.message);` Но думаю, что скорее всего какой-нибудь flush  в конце поможет.

Comment: @KoVadim событие onError() молчит. Ошибка заключается в не верной интерпретации самого фрейма закрытия. Должен быть активным влаги wasClenan, но он постоянно false.

Comment: попробуйте для начала просто не закрывать сокет (или не закрывать его сразу). Если ошибка уйдет - тогда flush поможет.

Comment: @KoVadim Я может что то не понял. Пробовал отправлять сообщение от клиента, потом посылал от сервера фрейм закрытия. Эффект тот же. Ставил '\r''\n' или '\n''\n'

Comment: если Вы отправляете данные и тут же закрываете соединение, то есть некая вероятность, что данные не добегут до клиента. То есть, со стороны клиента это выглядит как просто пришло закрытие сокета.

Comment: @KoVadim поставить задержку, скажем 5 сек, затем закрывать?

Comment: я об этом и говорю выше.

Comment: @KoVadim поставил задержку перед отправкой, 10 секунд и задержку закрытия соединения. Как только ушел закрывающий фрейм сразу у клиента закрытие с кодом 1006

Comment: перечитал [rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.5.1) - и там явно сказано, что после того, как одна сторона послала фрейм закрытия, другая на него отвечает. То есть, Вы должны дождаться ответа от клиента и только после этого закрыть соединение.

Comment: Пробовал так. Тоже после прочтения спецификации. Но попробую ещё раз

Comment: @KoVadim сервер посылает закрывающий фрейм и ждёт 3 секунду, в это время клиент отправляет закрытие фрейма socket.close(). Результат не изменился. Есть ещё идеи?

Comment: Ответ клиента вычитывается?

Comment: @KoVadim ответ от клиента это мое же фрейм закрытия, только естественно, с маской

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Долгожданный код 1000. Может кому то поможет обойти мои грабли.

1. Никакие флеши не нужны. Они тут не играют никакой роли, так как websocket прекрасно знает о длине всех элементов фрейма.
2. Задержки при обработке закрывающего фрейма вообще противопоказаны, так как websoket слушает и "делает свои заключения" через определенный интервалы времени.

В пункте 2 была одна из моих ошибок. Я наставил куча задержек полагая, что websocket не успевает получать или обрабатывать пакеты.

Главная ошибка заключалась в том, что закрывая соединение, делала это не полностью. То есть закрыл сокет, но не закрыл TCP, а для чистого закрытия соединения необходимо отправить закрывающий фрейм, дождаться ответа и тут же закрыть соккет, а затем соединение TCP(естественно речь о сервере). В моем случае клиент(браузер) приходил в недоумение видя закрытие сокета, но при этом открытое TCP соединение.

Прочитал много разной информации в поисках ошибки, но помогла самая малость, а именно:

> True, iff full WebSockets closing handshake was performed (close frame sent and 
>   received) *and* the server dropped the TCP (which is its
>   responsibility).

[Ссылка на ресурс](http://zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/autobahn-report-client/chrome_22_0_1229_94_case_7_9_5.html)